# Difference between System.getenv() & System.getProperty()

Tags: java, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between a System property and environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863674/whats-the-difference-between-a-system-property-and-environment-variable)

What is the difference between System.getenv() & System.getProperty()?

When we run any command using Processbuilder, we can set the environment variables ie:

```
String[] vCmd = { System.getenv("ANT_HOME") + "/bin/ant", "-f",
                ANT_BUILD_FILE, TARGET };
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(vCmd);
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();     
        env.put("CLASSPATH",
                antHome+"/lib/ant.jar:"
                        + antHome+"/lib/ant-launcher.jar:"
                        + antHome+"/lib/ant-nodeps.jar:"
                        );
        try{

            Process process = pb.start();
            InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            pb.wait();
        }
        catch(Exception e)

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());


        }
```

If I set some properties using System.setProperties() before this method , is it available to this process started by ProcessBuilder?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

[`System.getenv`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) gets an *environment variable*. [`System.getProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) gets a Java property. Environment variables are specified at the OS level. Java properties are specified by passing the `-D` option to the JVM (and can be set programmatically).

Answer (score 39):

[`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) is for Operating System environment variables, whereas [`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) is for JVM arguments which are passed as `-DpropName=value` to Java application launcher ([`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)).