# Running gcp cloud funtion locally using mvn function:run with ENV variables

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, maven-plugin

I want to run google cloud function locally, using function maven plugin command as below

`mvn function:run`

While running this I am giving some env variables with below syntax but I am not able to read these values in my function code. The system method  `System.getenv("VAR1")` returning null value.

`mvn function:run -DVAR1=value1 -DVAR2=value2 -DrunFunction.target=com.sample.MyFunction`

Can anyone guide/correct me on this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the values you are [passing using the -D flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112065/8935548), you will need to use `System.getProperty()` instead of `System.getenv()`.

Comment: Actually I wanted to use System.getenv(), and for this need the syntax to give ENV variables in mvn command line