# How to fix JRE issue when running jar with windows bat script

Tags: java

I have created a runnable jar with the following content in a MANIFEST file. This works fine when running the main class in eclipse and it is using JAVA_HOME that is set in my eclipse. I have also set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to my JDK installation path on my local. Now the problem is if run the same jar using below command, it is taking the different path instead of the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

I have tried running the  below command from the command line but still did not work as expected

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
java -jar my-jar-name.jar

in my source code, I am using System.getProperty("java.home") which prints
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211 .But I have set the JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211 in environment variables. If I run the echo %JAVA_HOME% manually on the command line, it prints correctly.

I expect that my jar prints the JAVA_HOME as below.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
But printing the actually below.
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211

There are no errors

Comment: sorry, no, I have set the java_home correctly. I have printed it by using echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: what is the output of System.getProperties()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME")`, which reads the environment variable used to point to your JDK. Using `System.getProperty("java.home")` is a system property that will point to your installed JRE. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441516/difference-between-java-home-and-java-home) goes into more detail about the differences between the two.

Comment: It worked fine. Thanks